# Function Definition: Matching two input lists

Tags: python, function, input, definition

```
def match_numbers (nlist, nlist1):
    '''Returns the integer string whose first three numbers are on the first list'''
    for x in nlist:
    for x in nlist1:
        print(x)
```

So suppose the first list was `['543', '432']` and the second list had `['543242', '43299919', '2322242', '245533']`, and I need the function to match `543` and `432` with its longer version on the second list, how can I get my code to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a large list, this will perform slightly better

```
list1 = ['543', '432']
list2 = ['543242', '43299919', '2322242', '245533']

def match_numbers (nlist, nlist1):
    results = {}
    for x in nlist1:
        results.setdefault(x[0:3], [])
        results[x[0:3]].append(x)

    for x in nlist:
        if x in results:
            print results[x]


match_numbers(list1, list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[x for x in a for i in b if i == x[:len(i)]]
```

Output:

> ['543242', '43299919']